# AWK reformat portion of results (names) within larger string

Tags: python, bash, awk

My goal is to reformat names from Last First Middle (**LFM**) to First Middle Last (**FML**), which are part of a larger string. Here's some sample data:

> Name, Address1, Address2
>   **Smith** Joe M, 123 Apple Rd, Paris TX
>   **Adams** Keith Randall, 543 1st Street, Salinas CA
>   **Price** Tiffany, 11232 32nd Street, New York NY
>   **Walker** Karen E F, 98 West Ave, Denver CO

What I would like is:

> Name, Address1, Address2
>  Joe M **Smith**, 123 Apple Rd, Paris
>   TX
>  Keith Randall **Adams**, 543 1st Street, Salinas CA
>   Tiffany **Price**, 11232 32nd Street, New York NY
>  Karen E F
>   **Walker**, 98 West Ave, Denver CO

I know how to reorder the first column, but I end up dropping the rest of the row data:

```
# Return the first colum via comma seperation (name), then seperate by spaces
# If there are two strings but not three (only a last and first name),
# then change the order to first last.

awk -F, '{print $1}'| awk -F" " '$2!="" && $3=="" {print $2,$1}' >> names.txt
awk -F, '{print $1}'| awk -F" " '$3!="" && $4=="" {print $3,$1,$2}' >> names.txt
...# Continue to iterate column numbers
```

If there's an easier way to put the last string found and  move it to the front I'd like to hear about it, but here's my real interest...

My problem is that I want to reorder the space separated fields of the 1st comma separated field (what I did above), ***but then also print the rest of the comma separated data.***

Is there a way I can store the address info in a variable and append it after the space seperated names?

Alternatively, could I do some kind of nested split?

I'm currently doing this with awk in bash, but am willing to use python/pandas or any other efficient methods.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following **AWK** script, as ugly as it is, works for your inputs (run with `awk -F, -f script.awk`):

```
{
 split($1, names, " "); 
 for (i=2; i<=length(names); i++) 
     printf("%s ", names[i]); 
 printf("%s, ", names[1]);
 for(i=2; i<NF; i++)
     printf("%s,", $i);
 print($NF)
}
```

Input:

```
Smith Joe M, 123 Apple Rd, Paris TX
Adams Keith Randall, 543 1st Street, Salinas CA
Price Tiffany, 11232 32nd Street, New York NY
Walker Karen E F, 98 West Ave, Denver CO
```

Output:

```
Joe M Smith,  123 Apple Rd, Paris TX
Keith Randall Adams,  543 1st Street, Salinas CA
Tiffany Price,  11232 32nd Street, New York NY
Karen E F Walker,  98 West Ave, Denver CO
```

The same solution in **Python**:

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    parts = re.split('\s*,\s*', line)
    names = parts[0].split()
    print(", ".join([" ".join(names[1:] + names[:1])] + parts[1:]))
```

Comment: There was a missing `-f` option (fixed).

Comment: As I said, there was an error in the answer. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed, looks terrible but works:

```
sed -E '2,$s/^([^ ,]*) ([^ ,]*)( [^,]*)?/\2\3 \1/' in
```

and POSIX version:

```
sed '2,$s/^\([^ ,]*\) \([^ ,]*\)\( [^,]*\)*/\2\3 \1/' in
```

*output:*

```
Name, Address1, Address2
Joe M Smith, 123 Apple Rd, Paris TX
Keith Randall Adams, 543 1st Street, Salinas CA
Tiffany Price, 11232 32nd Street, New York NY
Karen E F Walker, 98 West Ave, Denver CO
```

Comment: why did you backslash escape everything ?

Comment: what do you mean? you can see all escapes I have in the answer already.

Comment: I mean why did you escape capturing group parentheses and question mark instead of using extended regexp with `-r` ?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would not be POSIX compliant, but I guess it is. Changed.

Comment: You're right, it's not. -r is just for GNU sed and -E is just for newer versions of GNU sed plus OSX/BSD sed.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, its strange that the -E flag works with `--posix` flag. I would expect an error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk. This one works with the header line and Madonna (ie. single word fields):

```
$ awk '                     # using awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}           # csv
{
    n=split($1,a," ")       # split the first field to a
    for(i=n;i>1;i--)        # iterate back from the last element of a
        a[1]=a[i] " " a[1]  # prepending to the first element of a
    $1=a[1]                 # replace the first field with the first element of a
}1' file                    # output
```

Output:

```
Name, Address1, Address2
Joe M Smith, 123 Apple Rd, Paris TX
Keith Randall Adams, 543 1st Street, Salinas CA
Tiffany Price, 11232 32nd Street, New York NY
Karen E F Walker, 98 West Ave, Denver CO
Madonna, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=", " }
    $1 ~ / / {
        last = rest = $1
        sub(/ .*/,"",last)
        sub(/[^ ]+ /,"",rest)
        $1 = rest " " last
    }
    { print }
' file
Name, Address1, Address2
Joe M Smith, 123 Apple Rd, Paris TX
Keith Randall Adams, 543 1st Street, Salinas CA
Tiffany Price, 11232 32nd Street, New York NY
Karen E F Walker, 98 West Ave, Denver CO
```